# ios Core Data: How to change NSManagedObject without saving it to the context

Tags: ios, core-data, save, nsmanagedobjectcontext

i have let's say a NsMutableArray called "mArray" with fetched results from from a core data context. So, "mArray" contains some NSManagedObjects.

At some point i have to make some editing on those objects.

At a further point i will have to add some new NSManagedObjects to the context, also needing to save the context.

Now the new objects are save, but also the above editing on those objects are saved.

I woud like to be able to save only the new added NSManagedObjects to the context without the edits.

Can someone point me in the correct directions?

Thanks

Comment: If you add new entities, you don't need to save the context at that time. Just defer the save until you are completely ready.

Comment: i will have to save the context at some time, because i will need the new entries on the next app launch.

Comment: NSmutableArray *newArr = [mArray mutableCopy]. the objects in new array will point to the same objects in mArray, right?

Comment: Well, save in applicationWillTerminate:. That said, if you want to change the entities, and you don't ever want to save them, create new ones but never add them to the context, and use those to keep the temporary settings around.

Comment: Will it be safe to do MyObject * obj = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MyObject" inManagedObjectContext:nil]  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you save a context, you save everything in it.  If you want to work with some objects that do not save at the same time as other objects, you need to use multiple contexts.

See the documentation on NSManagedObjectContext, because using multiple contexts is not the easiest thing in the world.